How To Add An Allow Rule To UFW's before*.rules
I've appended to my /etc/ufw/before6.rules file the following
-A ufw6-before-input -p tcp -s XX.XX.XXX.XX -j ACCEPT
-A ufw6-before-output -p tcp -d XX.XX.XXX.XX -j ACCEPT

but still am not able to successfully connect unless I disable ufw firewall.
